# survplot - table with subjects of risk doesn't show up entirely

Tags: r, survival-analysis

this is a follow up to a previously asked, related question:
data and code are here [error message when ploting subjects at risk with survplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459078/error-message-when-ploting-subjects-at-risk-with-survplot)

When trying to plot the subjects at risk below the survplot, the table either overlaps with the labels of the x - axis or does not appear on the plot (in the example below one line is missing; totalps=4). How to solve this issue?

[image]

From the documentation to the survplot command, I understand that I may have to reset the margins of the plot with the par command (e.g. par(mar=c(5,4,4,2)+.1).) I don't understand how to include this par command into survplot.

Furthermore, there is considerable space between the lines of the table on the subjects at risk. Is there any direct way to reduce this space?

Here the code for the plot:

```
library(rms)
pdf(plot1.pdf)
survplot(KM.Duration.totalps[-1], 
         xlab="duration in months", ylab="survival prob",
         conf="none",
         label.curves=list(method="arrow", cex=0.8),
         time.inc=12,
         col=c(1:4),
         levels.only = FALSE,                   
         n.risk=TRUE,
         y.n.risk = -0.3, cex.n.risk = 0.6
         )

dev.off()
```

Comment: I don't know anything about survplot, but if you can post something using a built-in dataset, I'd be happy to poke around.

Comment: the main problem is that there are way too many tick marks for such a small amount of space. either make the plot much bigger (probably not the best solution) or limit the number of ticks to say 10 or fewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply reading the help page:

sep.n.risk
multiple of upper y limit - lower y limit for separating lines of text containing number of subjects at risk. Default is .056*(ylim[2]-ylim[1]).

And some par functions are best used with par just prior to the plot call (but after the pdf() call),  so:

```
pdf(...)
par( mar=c(7,4,4,2)+.1) ) # adds two lines to default space along bottom margin
survplot(...
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the margins before you plot, like so:

```
par(mar=(0,0,0,0))
plot(c(1:10))
```

will give you a plot with no margins. `par(mar=(1,2,3,4)` will give you a margin of one text line at the bottom, two on the left, three on the top, and four on the right.

If you want to specify the margins in inches use `par(mai=(x,x,x,x))`. The default for R is that an output device is 7 by 7 inches, although depending on the device (including ones I've written), that might be a little fuzzy.